# Accessing an Ethernet or USB port

Tags: windows, usb, raw-ethernet

Good Afternoon,
This post is to ask for ideas on which programming language for Windows Vista you would suggest for accessing raw data from an Ethernet port or a USB port. My strength is in micro-controllers. I have a project underway where the 32-bit micro-controller is the last processing device in a software defined radio. The micro has the capability to output digitized signals over a USB port or an Ethernet port. I would like to use the PC as a plotting tool to display the raw digitized sound as a waveform on the screen and possibly play the sound on the sound card output. Also, I will be creating FFT spectrum data, either in the 32-bit micro or in the PC, if the software is fast enough, for spectrum display on my laptop.
I have past experience with older VB. In my last project, I used a simple basic program (JustBasic) to send control data via a USB/RS232 device to a micro-controller. This interface is certainly not fast enough for this project. Additional future features would be to use the Ethernet or USB to control real time features i.e. filter frequencies, FFT size and sample rates in the micro-controller. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides the [Raw Input API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645536%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get data straight from a USB device.  You could use `C#` to access the port (see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/rawinput.aspx)), or any other .NET language.  You could also use C or C++ (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/16265/)).